# How to configure YAML multistage pipeline release stages in Azure test plan settings

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a multi-stage YAML pipeline using which I run my automated tests against different environments(Dev, Test, Pre-prod, etc). I wanted to run these automated tests directly from the test plan by configuring the build and release pipeline using Azure test plan settings.

But I couldn't see my release stages after selecting the build in the build pipeline dropdown. It is working fine for my classic UI release pipeline, not for the YAML muti-stage.

Does YAML multi-stage support this functionality?

[image: TestPlan settings]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to rely on the "old releases". But the steps and code it generates could easily be ported over to the new YAML pipelines. But you'd have to do it by hand.

You could create a temporary "old style" pipeline, configure it to see what all gets generated and then duplicate those tasks to your YAML pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I have converted my classic UI release pipeline tasks to YAML Mutistage, but those stages are not coming under test plan settings.

Comment: Right. And I don't think they will in the near future.